# Left join error in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform left join operation in R I am getting the below error is anyone has any idea what the error is trying to say.?

```
Feed <- left_join(sa_charge_new1, all_impact_files1, concated_column = concated_column)
```

Error:

```
 Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) :
    'translateCharUTF8' must be called on a CHARSXP'
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: `left_join` does not take an argument `concated_column = `.

Comment: my data is huge sa_charge_new1 file contains 177k records and all_impact_files1 contains 800k records and I cannot share the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is here:

```
left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches))
```

There is no argument passed by left_join() in the name of "concated_column". Read the description by ?left_join.